# How can I draw a blue rectangle when mouse is pressed?

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code. I want to draw a blue rectangle when the mouse is pressed. The rectangle would be centred around the mouse pointer. I am a noob to events, so I would appreciate help and explanations.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;  

 class MouseDemo extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
     int x, y; // location of mouse
     int sx=25, sy=25; // size of shape 
     JFrame frame;

     void buildIt() {     
         frame = new JFrame("MouseDemo");
         frame.add( this );
         this.x = 150;
         this.y = 150;
         this.addMouseListener(this); 
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(300, 300);
         frame.setLocation(200, 200);
         frame.setVisible(true);
     }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor( Color.blue );
         g.fillRect(x - sx/2, y - sy/2, sx, sy);
     }    

     // the method from MouseListener we're interested in this time
     @Override
     public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e) {
         e.getX();
         e.getY();
     }   

     // the other four methods from MouseListener
     // we don't use them, but they have to be present
     @Override public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e) { }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new MouseDemo().buildIt(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing right now and if you have any errors ...

Comment: right now, it just displays a JFrame with a blue square on the top left corner. and no reaction to mouseclicks. and no errors

Comment: Check this https://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/drawRectangleOnClick.html

Comment: thanks. it was just a problem of adding repaint().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your method to this:

```
 // the method from MouseListener we're interested in this time
 @Override
 public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e) {
     this.x = e.getX();
     this.y = e.getY();
     this.repaint();
 }
```

Your code draws the `Jpanel` with the square at the default point (150, 150). With the edit. You will change the default (150, 150) to what ever coordinates your mouse is and then tell the `JPanel` it should repaint itself what will call the `paintComponent` method that will draw the square at your mouse position.

Comment: nothing changed. I just a get a JFrame with a blue rectangle at the top left corner and no reaction to mouse

Comment: Hm, try with the repaint method instead of reevaluate. I edited the answer

Comment: yup. that fixed it